# Drawing a 3d plane in opengl given two vectors

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Okay, so I was attempting to draw a cube by drawing the 6 faces.

I define each of the faces of the cube itself by giving it two vectors. As follows:

[image]

However, now I am having trouble of how to draw these faces in openGL (just a small note, I am using LWJGL, which is the java library build upon openGL).

I have attempted to draw the said faces, but I believe I have a slight mistake that I can't seem to get right. Currently, I have attempted to draw the faces as follows:

```
public void render() {
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glVertex3f(v2.x, v1.y, v1.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(v1.x, v1.y, v1.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(v1.x, v2.y, v2.z);
    GL11.glVertex3f(v2.x, v2.y, v2.z);
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

But it seems here, that only the top and bottom faces get drawn correctly, while the side (left/right) faces aren't even visible.

How can I draw these properly?

Comment: It would help if you could clarify some things about your code. Since each face of the cube will require 4 vertices to make the quad for that face, I'm assuming that your render function only draws a single face of the cube, correct? Your definition of a Vector is a little confusing as well. Traditionally you would think of a Vector as having an X, Y, Z location and also a magnitude in the X, Y, and Z direction. You seem to have only 3 fields in your vector, are these supposed to be the magnitude or location of your vector?

Comment: To clarify- Yes, every single face is drawn using the render method I specified. Each vector here is a simple Vector3f object, which has an X, Y and Z location.

Comment: I believe that the X, Y, and Z components of the Vector3f class aren't meant to be used as magnitude of the vector and not the starting location of the vector. If you're using them purely as storage classes and not taking advantage of the other functions in the class then this may not be a big deal. You need to take into account the point at which your two vectors start (se a.lasram's post below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 vectors define infinity of parallel faces. You need an additional point `X` to select one of those unless your `X = (0,0,0)` and that's why it doesn't show in your code.

If `V1` and `V2` define the length and direction of two sides of a face that start from a reference point `X`, you can draw you quad as

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex3f(X.x, X.y, X.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(X.x+v1.x, X.y+v1.y, X.z+v1.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(X.x+v1.x+v2.x, X.y+v1.y+v2.y, X.z+v1.z+v2.z);
GL11.glVertex3f(X.x+v2.x, X.y+v2.y, X.z+v2.z);
GL11.glEnd();
```

Comment: This indeed solves the problem, I was confused with the vector as defined in mathematics and the vector3f in opengl. Adding an origin solved my problem. Thank you!